# how to compare two arrays with different size using php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays with different size

```
Array1 ( [26] => DJ [24] => APOLLO [36] => KLE [30] => Ajay [34] => RAJ [1] => Raj [2] => Globe ).

Array2( [0] => [1] =>  [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => [20] => [21] => [22] => [23] => [24] => [25] => [26] => [27] => [28] => [29] => [30] => [31] => [32] => [33] => [34] => [35] => [36] => )
```

how do i assign values of array1 to the respective keys in array2.

Comment: Edit to elaborate

Comment: what you really want?, this is not sufficient stuff to get your answer

Comment: @Ashok Khot if the size of two array are different then assign the element of array1 into array2 according to the array1 element key ? is this you want ?

Comment: assign the elements of array1 into array2 according to array1 element key and assign null or blank to remaining array2 elements

Comment: and the about size? does matter ? or do it only when the size of these array are differen ?

Comment: size should be of array2 size.

Comment: @Ashok Khot check my answer is this you want ? or something different so comment on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Ashok Khot simply use foreach() like below :

```
<?php
$Array1 = array(26 => "DJ", 24 => "APOLLO", 36 => "KLE", 30 => "Ajay", 34 => "RAJ", 1 => "Raj", 2 => "Globe");
$Array2 = array(0 => null, null, 1 => null,  2 => null, 3 => null, 4 => null, 5 => null, 6 => null, 7 => null, 8 => null, 9 => null, 10 => null, 11 => null, 12 => null, 13 => null, 14 => null, 15 => null, 16 => null, 17 => null, 18 => null, 19 => null, 20 => null, 21 => null, 22 => null, 23 => null, 24 => null, 25 => null, 26 => null, 27 => null, 28 => null, 29 => null, 30 => null, 31 => null, 32 => null, 33 => null, 34 => null, 35 => null, 36 => null);
foreach ($Array1 as $key => $value) {
    $Array2[$key] = $value;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($Array2);
```